# AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath is always set to ~/ for all ASP.NET Web API paths

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Currently, we are adding asp-net web api support to an asp.net application. However when using any path to request an action on the controller, AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath is always set to "~/" and results in 400 error. Used the route debugger available [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) confirmed that AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath is always incorrect no matter what the url is.

For e.g. all of below url accesses, has AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath as "~/"

```
http://localhost:1521/Testclient/apitest/values/get
http://localhost:1521/Testclient/apitest/values/get/1
```

Route debugger also shows failed/no match for above urls even though route table has required entries.

Have disabled all Application_BeginRequest/VPP/module/http handlers and anything that can cause routing to be impacted but still getting into same issue. Any other possible ways this can be debugged?

Update1: Checked the application.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath by handling Application_BeginRequest( ) in global.asax, even there it appears to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to have found the issue, site had a "." in the name and for some reason asp.net does not like it. Root path that caused the issue was

```
http://localhost:1521/Test.client/apitest/values/get
http://localhost:1521/Test.client/apitest/values/get/1
```

Note the "Test.Client", changed it to "TestClient" and all worked as expected. When i copied the link from the test machine, had changed it and overlooked it. This should save somebody few hours if they hit this problem. Still not sure if this is a bug!?

Comment: This is a bug in VS 2012 development server as well, and affects page routing for not only ASP.NET MVC, but also WebForms page routing as well.  I simply removed the period from the directory name and everything started working.  Thanks for posting this... it saved me hours as you suspected!